# Javascript templating libraries' intelligibility and their performance (compared to mine)

Tags: javascript

I've just started writing my own little templating library in javascript, because as I went through others, there is always this voice in head, which says: "Oh, this is a lot of code and functionality. Is that really necessary or would it slow down the performance?"

*If you are able to follow conventions, you would probably run into less issues.*

So I ended up with this little script with the upper quote in my head.
The convention, here is that *data* needs an object and its keys must be the same like in template, mentioned between those delimiter-brackets "{{key}}"

```
function Template(url, data) {

    this.url = url;
    this.data = data;

    this.delimiter = ['{{','}}'];


    this.load = function() {

        var string = new String();

        var http = null;
        if ( window.XMLHttpRequest ) {
            http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        http.open('GET', url, false);
        http.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if ( http.readyState === 4 ) {
                string = http.response;
            }
        };
        http.send(null);

        this.template = string;
        return this;

    };

    this.exchange = function() {

        for ( var key in this.data ) {

            var bracketedKey = this.delimiter[0] + key + this.delimiter[1];
            var indexOfKey = this.template.indexOf(bracketedKey);
            var lengthOfKey = bracketedKey.length;

            var exchange = this.template.substring(indexOfKey, indexOfKey+lengthOfKey);

            this.template = this.template.replace(exchange, this.data[key]);

        }

        return this;

    };

    this.build = function(selector) {

        this.load();
        this.exchange();

        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = this.template;
        div = div.firstChild;

        if ( typeof selector === 'string' ) {
            document.querySelector(selector).appendChild(div);
        } else {
            return div;
        }

    };

}
```

But now I've started thinking about the fact, that other libraries include more code than mine and there must be a reason for it, mustn't it?

There also a few more thingg, that are coming to my head, like:

1. Less code = better performance?
2. Why do so many people relate their projects with this templating libraries?
   (Matter of performance => that would refute my first point)

It'd be cool, if someone could explain me a few things about this topic.

1. Am I right with my mindset?
2. When I am right, is there something that I could improve, or even when I am wrong?
3. If you would recommend a library to me, what is your reason?

Comment: you may want to post this over at codereview.stackexchange.com, where it probably won't get closed and may even get a decent answer.

Comment: okay, I'll do it, thanks for your suggestion :)

Comment: It looks as though you're mixing AJAX into templating, which is better addressed separately.

Comment: but when I do not use ajax to load the template, what is the better way to get the template file or do you suggest me to save the template into a variable directly into the script iself? for me there isn't any other way to deal with it, which I'm aware of

Answer (score 2):

One man's **complexity** is another's **functionality**. In example, can your simple tempating system do conditionals (if var is true, do this section of template)? What about iterating over an array? What about partial templates included at template-time? What about while looping through an array access data that was in the context one step up?

As a developer of my own Javascript/CF/Go templating system, https://github.com/owenallenaz/Goatee, I can say that it always starts simple, but then the real world gets in the way and you actually have to do things. This means adding complexity and you try and do it in the most responsible way possible, constantly weighing the cost of whether the addition will make developer's lives easier and not encourage bad behavior (such as processing data at template time).

Comment: you've mentioned good questions, which I'll definitely think about, thanks :)